# Uitableview cell selection with integer identifier

Tags: sql, xcode, uitableview, cell

I have managed to create my uitableview which is filled with sql quiz data. Now i am trying to create a select deselect method. After the checkmark of cells i want to press the start button and with the checked options, i am thinking to comes up a new playgamescreen with mixed quiz questions from selected categories. Is that possible to work?

Here is Some code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if ([self isRowSelectedOnTableView:tableView atIndexPath:indexPath]) {
        [self.selectedCells removeObject:indexPath];
        cell.accessoryType =UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }else{
            [self.selectedCells addObject:indexPath];
            cell.accessoryType =UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }

            NSNumber * selectedRow = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row];
                NSLog(@"%@", selectedRow);
                startButton.tag = selectedRow?10:0;
    }
```

And here is my try for the button action

```
- (IBAction)startAction:(id)sender
{
if([sender tag] == 10){
    PlayViewController * controller = [[PlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlayViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The tag is only a try for the button. What i am really trying is to read the selected row number and with that to create the sql statement for the play view controller. Is it possible?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand what you are trying to do.

However in didSelectRowAtIndexPath you do not need to define the cell again. You have the indexPath.row value which indicates which line of the table is selected. You can store that value for later use. You can also store the selected record.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   selectedRow = indexPath.row;  // store the table row number
      // or
   selectedRecord=[fullTableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  // store the value
```